# How to flash error for particular validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to flash messages in a form when they do not meet the validation requirements but can't work out how to achieve this.

I have the following setup:

models/item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :condition, :day, :description, :subtitle, :title

  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 20 }

  belongs_to :user
end
```

controllers/items_controller.rb

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def new
    @item = Item.new
end

def show
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
end

def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(params[:item])
    if @item.save
        flash[:success] = "Your item has been saved"
        redirect_to root_path
    else

        render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @item.destroy
        redirect_back_or root_path
    end

end
```

and finally views/items/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Items Base</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">

        <%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>

        <%= f.label :title, "Title" %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>

        <%= f.label :subtitle, "Subtitle" %>
        <%= f.text_field :subtitle %>

        <%= f.label :condition, "Condition" %>
        <%= f.number_field :condition %>

        <%= f.label :description, "Description" %>
        <%= f.text_field :description %>

        <%= f.label :day, "Day" %>
        <%= f.text_field :day %>

        <%= f.submit "List", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

Essentially I would like to be able to flash the message "Description too short!" when the user leaves it blank or below 20 characters, or flash the message "Title required" if it is left blank.  Any thoughts on how best to achieve this.  Also if anyone has any good resources on working with the flash it would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I do it:

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@client) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <%= f.label :company_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :company_name %> 
  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

And here is my error_messages partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's perfect thanks. Where are the messages stored though for example I used your example and received the error flash "Description is too short (minimum is 20 characters),"  Where can you customize these, I've hunted around the app files and can't find where these messages originate. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tom You do it in your models. Just add `message: "Hey, you need to be longer! (min 20 characters)"`